# yml unable to loop over string \ array

Tags: loops, yaml, github-actions, cicd

I am using a github action to validate json against its particular schema. This is working, however, not 100% to what we need.

When a file fails we do not know exactly which file has gone kaput so would like to detect files done individually.

I have this workflow

```
name: JSON Schema Validation

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      CHANGED_FILES:
        required: true
        type: string


jobs:

  verify-json-validation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - ${{ each changedFile in inputs.CHANGED_FILES }}:
            verify-json-validation:
            runs-on: ubuntu-latest
                steps:
                  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
                  - name: Validate JSON Schema
                    uses: cardinalby/schema-validator-action@v2
                    with:
                    file: changedFile
                    schema: 'schemas/notificationConfiguration.schema.json'
```

However the problem is the loop and I get this error message

> Property ${{ each env in inputs.CHANGED_FILES }} is not allowed.

I have found this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml#add-support-for-string-split-function-in-yaml-template-expressions

which suggests what I am doing should be possible.

I have also tried this too for the loop

```
- ${{ each env in split(toJson(inputs.CHANGED_FILES) | '', ', ') }}:
```

and

```
- ${{ each env in split(inputs.CHANGED_FILES | '', ', ') }}:
```

and

```
- ${{ each env in split(inputs.CHANGED_FILES, ', ') }}:
```

to no avail.

I would be grateful if someone could let me know what and where I have gone wrong and how to resolve.

Comment: The workflow you posted is GitHub Actions workflow and the link you attached is for the Azure DevOps. As of now, GitHub Actions doesn't support this.

Comment: @Azeem this was my mistake in the assumption that it would work as both are using yml.  I have since found strategy matrix and this  working now. 

I will post an answer to my question shortly to help others

Comment: Right. Yes, using a matrix would make more sense if you don't want to loop in the shell via some CLI tool. BTW, please check existing answer on SO before posting yours. IIRC, there are multiple questions with the same use case. Thanks!